# Avira free and Vista firewall

Tags: windows-vista, anti-virus, windows-firewall

The Vista firewall is preventing Avira free antivirus from updating...when I temp disable the firewall all is fine...I have checked the settings for the firewall and they are ok for Avira but still no luck...I have also cleaned the registry of remnants of previously uninstalled applications...Any ideas? Thank You

Comment: To clarify - with the firewall *disabled*, Avira can update like normal, but with the firewall *enabled*, you cannot?

Answer (score 1):

Add an exception to the Windows Firewall for Avira Update:

Go to Start -> Control Panel -> Security and click on **Allow a Program through Windows Firewall**

[image]

Click **Add program...** and navigate to this file:

```
C:\Program Files\Avira\AntiVir Desktop\update.exe
```

Comment: Molly's always got the answer!